# Redirect to post_id?

Tags: redirect

I am using a Simple 301 Redirects plugin and I understand that this requires the redirect to be a permalink.

Is there any way I can redirect to a post_id? That way I can move the post (or page in this case) and then I don't have to worry about rewriting the direct URL.

Thanks.

Comment: You have **tons of open Qs**. Could you please start answering the comments and answers there? **THANK YOU**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) will automatically create a redirection rule when the postname is changed. If you use that (possibly in tandem with simple 301's, though you'd be creating some overhead that way), you can work around it. It should be noted that I have never used simple 301's, but I've used Redirection extensively.

Comment: Awesome this is what i needed.